# Change hostname and prompt in OS X terminal

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal, prompt, hostname

On a Mac the hostname and prompt is:

```
workstation:~ thomas$
```

On Ubuntu Linux it would be:

```
thomas@workstation:~$
```

**How can I make the OS X prompt look like the Ubuntu one?**

Comment: The word you were looking for is "prompt", and you'll probably find a lot more information now, when doing a search for it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run this command in terminal

```
PS1="[\u@\h:\w]$ "
```

here

- u represents username
- h represents hostname
- w represents current working directory

This is temporary, that means after running this command if you close the terminal again, the default prompt will appear.

If you want to set permanently, then insert below line in your `.bash_profile` file under your home directory:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h:\w]$ "
```

Comment: You forgot the colon `:`, and the syntax in OS X is the same, since it also uses bash.